# Access the files stored in Azure File Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-storage, azure-files

I have uploaded some files to cloud file share via my MVC app. All good up till now.

Now i want to show link, set image source from the file share, but can't access the files from web browser. For eg, if i show an image with image source set to

https://mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net/content/images/14_large_image.png

I get nothing and when i try to browse this file in web browser, i get following error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
  <Error><Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code><Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
  RequestId:8294dc3b-001a-00f5-1b96-9039c3000000
  Time:2016-04-07T06:26:33.3731376Z</Message><HeaderName>x-ms-version</HeaderName><HeaderValue/></Error>
```

I think this could be credentials issue as but I am not sure. Any pointers please!

Comment: Did you set public access to your cloud file ? (I usually use BLOB storage, and it is easy to control by using Azure Storage Explorer that File Storage)

Comment: Client gave me the file storage credentials. Dont know if it was set to public or not, but will check with him.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to access Azure file storage is via SMB or Rest. There is not HTTP interface available.

From [Get started with Azure File storage on Windows](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/)

> File storage offers shared storage for applications using the standard SMB 2.1 or SMB 3.0 protocol. Microsoft Azure virtual machines and cloud services can share file data across application components via mounted shares, and on-premises applications can access file data in a share via the File storage API.

If you need anonymous HTTP access then you would need to use blob storage instead which has a {storagename}.blob.core.windows.net address

In order to access the files from HTTP (Rest) you need to first create the authorization headers, which are documented under the [Get File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn194274.aspx) documentation. The required authentication header is documented at [Authentication for the Azure Storage Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx) The format of which is

> Authorization="[SharedKey|SharedKeyLite] {AccountName}:{Signature}"

I'd expect it be possible to use an SAS token for the signature, but I've just tried this and I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: But why does it mention this? URL format: Files are addressable using the following URL format:
https://<storage account>.file.core.windows.net/<share>/<directory/directories>/<file>

The following example URL could be used to address one of the files in the diagram above:
http://samples.file.core.windows.net/logs/CustomLogs/Log1.txt

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: Under file storage concepts on the link you shared.

Comment: I think the files are accessbile. See the error that i got at top. https://recruitsystemtest.file.core.windows.net/content/documents/14_Post-card-generic.pdf

Comment: @user869375 I have amended the answer - I think that is badly worded in the documentation as it doesn't make it clear that it is intended as a Rest request and not a straight HTTP

Comment: I read about this, but the problem is that you need to setup the shared key with end timestamp (cant be permanent)....So if i have to point to some image file and show it on website as ImageSrc, this wont work....Very poor documentation indeed. At least if they had shared something that you can't view files directly in browser, i would have wasted time in choosing blob over file storage.

Comment: If you are using the files for website access, you should really be using blob storage, which is what it is created for (and has appropriate HTTP header access) file storage is primarily designed for SMB access, it would take quite a degree of work to make that work as website storage

Comment: true.....was using blog in an earlier project as well, just thought it to be an improvement over blob and gave it a try. Silly me :)

Comment: It it possible to access a file in the file storage directly - I did the following yesterday:
* upload a file using Azure Portal,
* download it ;) - in the downloaded file list (in Chrome) - copy the download URL
* you get an URL like: https://azurevpngroup1184.file.core.windows.net/test%2Finstall-querona-driver.sh?sv=2015-04-05&ss=bqtf&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2016-06-06T17%3A25%3A03Z&sig=iiYuf6zczOHNJU7TmZxvRxZr73U2FeuWFWkAsaQPTfE%3D
Not very convenient and probably the key won't last for too long but in short-term it works.